# Differences between slashes and ' '

Tags: php, escaping, quotes, double-quotes

Sorry if there is a question that's very similar to this or if there is answer somewhere else but I have a question that's been on my mind lately.

Most people that are versed in programming languages and strings would know that you can escape quotations with a slash (\")

Ex:  `echo "<input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" id=\"brandid\" value=\"submit\" />\n";`

But what I usually do is use ' inside of " instead of slashes.  So the code above would look something like this:

```
echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' id='brandid' value='submit' />\n";
```

Could someone explain the differences between the two and the advantages or disadvantages between the two?  Sorry if I didn't use the correct terminology or am missing something.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: whatever is more readable is better. note that you can also use single quotes for `echo` and then leave double quotes inside normally

Comment: @MarkoD but the `\n` won't work if you do that ...

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV In his example, I doubt he needs `\n`, but `<br />`. Anyway, I just mentioned that he has a third option too. He also has an option to use double quotes inside single quotes and then concatenate with `"\n"` if he really needs it

Comment: Neither are better.  You should really separate your php code from your presentation.  If you do that, you don't even need to worry about it.

Comment: Those are backslashes and not slashes.

Comment: Thanks, that actually isn't my code, I was looking at a different question on saw that somebody put in that line as an answer and used back slashes, but thanks for all of those tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you like, and what you need to do.  If I've got a lot of variable substitution I need to do, double quotes and curly braces (if needed) are the way to go.  I personally don't like adding extra unnecessary markup (read: escaping) if I don't need to.

```
echo "Hello \"$username\", your last visit was on $lastVisit at $time";
```

As opposed to...

```
echo 'Hello "'.$username.'", your last visit was on '.$lastVisit.' at '.$time;
```

If it's simple HTML markup and no variable substitution is required, then single quotes are fine.

```
echo '<a href="index.php">Home</a>';
```

No right answer here.

Comment: Thanks for those tips.  I usually use your second sample of code.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the difference isn't much. You can use either of them. This is noticeable for some JavaScript events which need a value to be passed too

```
echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' onclick='MyAwesomeFunction(\"a string\", \"to be\", \"passed here\");' />\n";
```

Though, I'd prefer the following:

```
?>
<input name='submit' type='submit' onclick='MyAwesomeFunction("a string", "to be", "passed here");' />
<?php
```